# Having trouble creating a loop to check if two columns of a matrix are similar (2D arrays, Java)

Tags: java, arrays, search, similarity

So I was practicing 2D arrays in Java and I have this exercise that asks me to create 2 functions, one that receives a matrix, a column number and a value and checks how many times the value shows in a certain column of the matrix, and a second one that checks if 2 columns are similar.
2 columns are considered similar if each value only shows once in each column, both columns contain the same values (they don't have to be in the same order).
I haven't found a drill that tackles the same task online and I would also want to learn why my logic is wrong so I can learn in the future.
I am obligated to use the first function in the 2nd drill.
I was able to make the first function work but then when I got to the point where I have to check if 2 columns are similar I couldn't make it work, I tried multiple loops for the search method but none of them worked properly.

This is the code I am currently running which is not working:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex_4 {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int drill;
        System.out.println("Please enter the drill number you would like to test:");
        drill = input.nextInt();
        switch (drill) {
            case (1) -> {
                int[][] num = createMatrix();
                System.out.print("Please enter a value and the number of a column in the matrix: ");
                // please refer to the first column as 0 and not 1.
                int val = input.nextInt();
                int col = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("The amount of times this value shows in the column is: %d", numInColumn(num, col, val));
            }
            case (2) -> {
                int[][] similar = createMatrix();
                System.out.print("Please enter the number of two columns in the matrix: ");
                // please refer to the first column as 0 and not 1.
                int col1 = input.nextInt();
                int col2 = input.nextInt();
                if (similarColumns(similar, col1, col2)) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("false");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[][] createMatrix() {
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of rows of the matrix: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of columns of the matrix: ");
        int columns = input.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];
        System.out.println("Please enter the values of the matrix:");
        int j, i;
        for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
                /*
                The user needs to enter values of the matrix in this order for example:
                row 1: column 1 -> column 2.
                row 2: column 1 ->column 2.
                 */
                matrix[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    public static int numInColumn(int[][] num, int col, int val) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (num[i][col] == val) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static boolean similarColumns(int[][] similar, int col1, int col2) {
        boolean isSimilar = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < similar.length; i++) {
                if ((numInColumn(similar, col1, similar[i][col2]) != 1)) {
                    isSimilar = false;
                }
        }
        return isSimilar;
    }
}
```

for example the matrix:

```
 4 5 4 5 
 3 7 3 2 
 2 4 2 9 
 2 9 2 5 
 1 2 1 4
```

should return false if I check for column's 1 and 3, but it returns true.

this matrix:

```
 4 5 4 7 
 3 7 3 2 
 2 4 2 9 
 2 9 2 5 
 1 2 1 4
```

should return true for columns 1 and 3 and it does.

Answer (score 0):

Great phrasing of your first question, and thankyou for providing such a good code example and examples of what you have tried. The good news I have for you is that your logic in determining if column A is "similar" to column B is correct. The bad news is that this **does not** imply that column B is similar to column A.

Notice that in your first test case, the value 5 appears twice in column 3. This means that as your code iterates down the column, it has successfully found an instance of each number that appears in column 3, and therefore returned true. If you swap the column indexes however ([3,1] instead of [1,3]), your code will then try to find a match for each value in column 1, and fail to find the value 7. This is where your algorithm is breaking down.

You have a couple of options here, depending on your interpretation of the instructions.

1. Run the same check you have currently in **both** directions. This will check that if a value appears in one column, it must also appear at least once in the other. However, this may be the incorrect result, depending on the instructions given.
2. Remove values from **both** columns (or a working copy of the columns) as you check off each pair of values. In this instance you will only need to run your check once, however, it will require that the same number of each digit appears in both columns, and will also be marginally more complicated to produce.

As an example of how these two methods differ, consider the two columns below.

```
2 2
2 3
2 3
2 3
```

Method 1 will return true; both columns contain 2's, and both contain 3's, no issue! However, Method 2 will return false, as the number of 2's is not equal to the number of 3's.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the compliments and for the detailed answer. If I may ask, I don’t think the solution you offered checks if each value only repeats once in each column, could you offer advice on how to do that as well? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your script will solve that currently due to the `if ((numInColumn(similar, col1, similar[i][col2]) != 1))` condition, provided that you run the script in both directions as I detailed in the 1st option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in your `similarColumns` method.  In it, you are only comparing one column with the value from the other column.  In the case of your first example, Each value from column 2 `{5,2,9,5,4}` exists only once in column 1 `{5,7,4,9,2}`.  Even though 5 appears twice in column 2, it only appears once in column 1.  Therefore, the conditional `!= 1` passes for both instances of 5 in column 2.

You can fix this easily enough by extending your code to repeat the check in the opposite direction

```java
public static boolean similarColumns(int[][] similar, int col1, int col2) {
  boolean isSimilar = true;
  for (int[] ints : similar) {
    if (numInColumn(similar, col1, ints[col2]) != 1 && numInColumn(similar, col2, ints[col1]) != 1) {
      isSimilar = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return isSimilar;
}
```

If you are able to use non-primitive Objects and types, you can also accomplish this fairly easily without loops using the Java8 Stream api.  I'd recommend rotating your columns to rows to make it a bit easier as well.  Something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] my2dArray = new int[][]{
    {4, 5, 4, 7},
    {3, 7, 3, 2},
    {2, 4, 2, 9},
    {2, 9, 2, 5},
    {1, 2, 1, 4}};

  /* creates new array
    {4, 3, 2, 2, 1},
    {5, 7, 4, 9, 2},
    {4, 3, 2, 2, 1},
    {7, 2, 9, 5, 4},
   */
  int[][] rotatedArray = new int[my2dArray[0].length][my2dArray.length];

  rotate(my2dArray, rotatedArray);

  for (int i = 0; i < rotatedArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < rotatedArray.length; j++) {
      System.out.println("Column " + i + " is similar to Column " + j + ": " + similarColumns(rotatedArray[i], rotatedArray[j]));
    }
  }
}

private static boolean similarColumns(int[] column1, int[] column2) {

  // creates a sorted array of distinct values
  int[] filteredColumn1 = Arrays.stream(column1).distinct().sorted().toArray();
  int[] filteredColumn2 = Arrays.stream(column2).distinct().sorted().toArray();

  // if the length changed, then the column contained duplicate values
  boolean lengthUnchanged = filteredColumn1.length == column1.length && filteredColumn2.length == column2.length;

  return Arrays.equals(filteredColumn1, filteredColumn2) && lengthUnchanged;
}

private static void rotate(int[][] oldArray, int[][] rotatedArray) {
  for (int i = 0; i < oldArray[0].length; i++) {
    for (int j = oldArray.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      rotatedArray[i][j] = oldArray[j][i];
    }
  }
}
```

Another way to remove duplicate values would be to assign the array to a `HashSet`.  A `HashSet` can only contain unique values, so something like:

```java
int[] filteredColumn1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(IntStream.of(column1).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new))).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sorted.toArray();
```

would also work, although it may be a bit overly complicated.